# What is this ornamental, yellow flower that looks like a smooth pineapple skin?

Tags: species-identification, flowers

My mom got this in her Mother's Day arrangement and we have no idea what it is.

[image: yellow flower that looks like a smooth pineapple skin]

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. As it is ornemental, the question might be a better fit on [Garderning.SE](gardening.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I don't understand why there are already 2 close votes in this question. Asking for species identification is perfectly valid here at biology SE. Is the issue just the fact that the plant in question is an ornamental one? It makes no sense to me.

Comment: The problem here is different, @Tytoalba. The discussion on Meta talks about a good answer making it worth to keep a question, be it a good or a bad question. What I'm asking here is: why the close votes in the first place? `species-identification` tag doesn't explicitly says *"just for non-ornamental species"* or anything like that. OP just wants to know the species of that plant, that's it. It makes no difference if the plant is in a park, in a forest or in his/her mom's table.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado See the last [paragraph](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3576/whats-the-point-of-closing-well-answered-and-well-received-questions/3577#3577) of Madscientist's answer. I didn't remember the question, and wrongly said valid 'discussion', I'll remove it now.

Comment: I've read it, thanks, but I'm still think the issue here is unrelated to that discussion.

Comment: The issue is not the fact that the plant is ornamental, but the fact that identifying cut flowers makes it impossible to define the "localization" of the species. For anything grown in the garden, we would at least know that it can grow in that specific location. Here we have very little to go with (even if it could be identified successfully this time).

Answer (score 16):

This is a beehive ginger, [*Zingiber spectabile*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zingiber_spectabile).

Its inflorescence will become a bit different sometime soon:

[image]

I believe the one in your image is not yet fully developed, like this one here:

[image]

Source of the images:

- http://www.geneticjungle.com/2008/08/deceptive-petals-7-orchid-mimics.html
- http://specialflowersintheworld.blogspot.com.au/2015/04/zingiber-spectabile-flower.html